# Writing checked items to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

These are my many checkboxes and I need to grab the selected ones on a save and create an array/string of numbers that will be saved.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="4" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Do I need to add a value with a number so that i can get the number that the checkbox is so i can get something like "1,4,8,9"(checkboxes selected) or can I get it from ID?

I was looking at something like this as an example:

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnClick').click(function(){
    var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT:

Is there a way to get the checkboxes specifically by starting ID as to not get every single one from the page?

Comment: Are you trying to map IDs to values? What does the actual rendered HTML look like? And what is your desired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.push` on Array's like so:

```
val.push(this.id);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dpMp2/3/

or

you can just do this:

```
var val = $.makeArray($(':checkbox:checked'));
```

information on `makeArray` can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/
*note* as `am not i am` stated below, the array will be objects and you will have to get the id or value from each obj. Read the docs for more info.

Comment: Using `.push()` wouldn't change the outcome. and `$.makeArray` would not give you the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
$(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); })
```

Comment: Don't forget `.toArray()` at the end if OP wants an actual Array.

Answer (score 0):

Since val is an object, so you'll have to use `push` function to assign the data.

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnClick').click(function(){
    var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val.push($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't have to use `.push()`. OP's method is just as valid.